# Telegram Bot, force_reply doesn't match message_id

Tags: api, telegram-bot

for some reason when I force a reply from the user I get a wrong ID back on the user "callback"

it always seems to miss by one, for example the originating message_id is `403` and when the user replies I get `reply_to_message":{"message_id":402`

Any idea what it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a while I finally understood how it works so I'm leaving it here in case someone falls into this little problem.

You have to consider that the resulting message_id is what is generated when you send a message to telegram, if you don't see it just make a print of your curl request, you'll see it :)